# is it possible to use import after sys.exit(1)?

Tags: python, exception, exit

I have a `GetVars()` function (not supposed to be changed), it throws `sys.exit(1)` in some cases.
I want to do some cleanup for this case:

```
try:
  common_func.GetVars()
except SystemExit:
  cmdline = "-user user1"
  sys.argv = ['config.py', cmdline]
  import config
```

`config.py` should take some args, but it contains the only `print` statement for now. But it is not executed - is there any way to do it? Just trying to understand what happens, I know the code looks odd :)

UPD:
now I'm trying to run

```
cur_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
gcti_cfgDir = os.path.join(cur_dir, "..", "cfg-scripts")
 sys.path.append(gcti_cfgDir)
import config
try:
  sys.exit(1)
except SystemExit:
  try:
    import config
  except:
    print "errr"
```

Comment: perhaps try calling your config.py file using `os` or `subprocess` instead of importing it, since you said it takes args?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried it with this `mymodule.py` file:

```
$ cat mymodule.py 
import sys

try:
  sys.exit(1)
except SystemExit:
  cmdline = "-user user1"
  sys.argv = ['config.py', cmdline]
  import config
```

and with this `config.py` file:

```
$ cat config.py 
print "Everything is ok for now"
```

The result is the expected one:

```
$ python mymodule.py 
Everything is ok for now
```

I am mostly sure the problem is not in the import per se, neither in the `SystemExit` capturing... Probably your `config.py` file is broken.

**UPDATE**: Ah, I believe I got it!

According to your new code, you are importing the `config` module before the `sys.exit(1)` and importing it in the `except` block, too:

```
import config # <-- here...
try:
  sys.exit(1)
except SystemExit:
  try:    
    import config # <-- and here
  except:
    print "errr"
```

However, the code of the module *is executed just at the first import*. The following ones either put the module in the namespace or, if it is already in the namespace, do nothing.

The best solution, as I see it, is to define a function inside your module. If this is the content of your module:

```
print "Everything is ok for now"
```

just replace it by

```
def run():
    print "Everything is ok for now"
```

And instead of importing the module where you want it to be executed, import it only once and call the function:

```
import config # This line just imports, does not print nothing
config.run()  # OTOH, this one prints the line...
try:
  sys.exit(1)
except SystemExit:
  try:    
    config.run() # This one prints the line too
  except:
    print "errr"
```

Actually, this is surely the best way of dealing with code in Python: put code into functions, put functions into modules, call the functions. It is not generally a good practice to put your executable code directly inside the module, as you were trying to do.

**2nd UPDATE**: If you cannot change the code of the `config.py` module, you can still call it using [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) to call the Python interpreter. You can even pass the parameters you were trying to add to `sys.argv`:

```
import subprocess
# ...
subprocess.call(['python', 'config.py'])
try:
  sys.exit(1)
except SystemExit:
  try:
    subprocess.call(['python', 'config.py',  "-user", "user1"])  # Extra args
  except:    
    print "errr"
```

Comment: config.py contatins just 1 line with print "hi!"

Comment: @Francheska oh, I think I found the problem. Read my updated question.

Comment: Thank you!! Unfortunatelly I can't amend those code to add functions but now I understand what happens

Comment: @Francheska so, there is still another solution. See my new Update.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) module to register cleanup handlers or if you're sure that `GetVars` is calling `sys.exit`, monkey patch the latter to throw a custom exception instead of really running so that you can catch it and manually handle it.

Comment: you can catch SystemExit; there is no need for a custom exception

Comment: Good point. I still think `atexit` is the right way to go though.